# C#: How to initialize a record that has a List?

Tags: c#, monogame

got a question that I hope is easy to answer!

I'm self teaching myself C# right now - I do know JavaScript and PHP so far. One thing I've been struggling with is how to deal with List<>, Dictionary<> etc, with regard to actually initiating these things - if that makes sense.

So for example, I have the record:

```
 record Beat(string beat, int note, List<int> loc, bool powerup);
```

but I'm having the hardest of time actually declaring this record. For example, I tried this:

```
Beat beat = new Beat("00:00", 2, [200,400], true);
```

or even

```
Beat beat = new Beat("00:00, 2, new(200,400), true);
```

which both produce errors and I just can't figure out how i'm supposed to declare this.

So I appreciate any help or pointing in the right direction. I tried to Google it but couldn't formulate the query correctly! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a list, you will need to create a new one, and (optionally) add stuff to it.

ex:

```cs
Beat beat = new Beat("00:00", 2, new List<int> { 200, 400 }, true);
```

Alternatively, if you were to change your parameter to an `ICollection<int>`, you would have a bit more flexibility, and you could use the array syntax, which is a bit less typing

```cs
Beat beat = new Beat("00:00", 2, new [] { 200, 400 }, true);
```

Comment: In this situation, methinks `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` is preferable to `ICollection<T>`, especially as it's covariant whereas `ICollection<T>` is invariant.

Comment: Thank you all so much. Your answer works! ... and made me realize that maybe this isn't the best way of storing data I want too? Essentially charting out a beat map for a song.

Comment: @sylargaf tbh I don't know enough about that domain to be able to help you regarding data structure. Depends on what you'll end up doing with it in the end.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, you can initialize with curly brackets, and specify the property names; like this:

```
    Beat b = new Beat { beat = "xxx", note = 100, loc = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 5 }, powerup = false };
```